# Is it possible to make a redirect using the browser's default back button using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following scenario on my website.. When a user is on the payment(checkout) page and hits the back button, an error page is displayed by default (magento tricky stuff).

I would like my user to be redirected on the homepage!

Is this possible using javascript/jquery, or using html5 push state?

Any help would much be appreciated.

Comment: The tricky thing which i cannot understand.. how to bind an event on the back btn..that's not possible

Comment: You could do something with `window.onunload`? Or `window.onload` on whatever page is loaded when they hit the back button and check the referrer.

Comment: @putvande: thanks => window.onunload seems to do the trick !

Answer (score -1):

Try this for back: `history.back(-1);`

This is a back button I made:

```
document.getElementById('exit').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    history.back(-1);
});

<button id="exit"></button>
```

Comment: i think you didnt understand the question

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. but how is it possible to bind this event.. we don't have control on the back button..

Comment: The Magneto templates are really inflexible if you can't make a simple button :( How do you expect to make anything if the need arises?

Comment: @MeeneshJain Wow you flagged Jonathan Brooks and down voted me within minutes of posting. Your diligence is extraordinary.

Comment: @zer00ne i am a active member for 2 years and visit site daily, stay on SO for almost 4 hours continues so you may call it a experience

Comment: @MeeneshJain I am inexperienced, I focus too much on the OP's question and try to answer it.

Comment: @zer00ne keep it up... if you need any help, i will be happy to help